# php call function with echo from within function

Tags: php, recursion, echo

I've been struggling with this for hours and can't find any info on the net.
I have a create_header function which outputs the html then dynamically creates the category list from the database using a recursive function (called render_tree). This function uses echo to output the relevant html.

When I try to run this function from with the create_header function, it doesn't output anything. I've tried including the render_tree function with the create_header function to make sure it is accessible, but obviously I'm still doing something wrong

```
create_header()
{
?> <html>...

<?php
$conn = db_connect();

function renderTree($parent = "0")
{
//Category Menu - Main recursive function. I'll asume '0' id is the root node
global $categoryNames;
global $childrenTree;

$children = $childrenTree[$parent];
if($parent != "0")
{
    if ($categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]] == 1)
    {
        if (count($children) == 0 && $categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]] == 2)
            echo "<a class='subexpandable' href='item_list.php?cat=$parent'>" . $categoryNames[$parent] . "</a>\n";
        if (count($children) == 0 && $categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]] == 1)
            echo "<a class='menu' href='item_list.php?cat=$parent'><h3 class='menuheader'>" . $categoryNames[$parent] . "</h3></a>\n";
        else
            echo "<h3 class='menuheader expandable'>" . $categoryNames[$parent] . "</h3>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if (count($children) == 0)
            echo "<li><a href='item_list.php?cat=$parent'>", $categoryNames[$parent], "</a></li>\n";
        else
            echo "<li><a class='subexpandable' href='item_list.php?cat=$parent'>", $categoryNames[$parent], "</a></li>\n";
    }
}
if(count($children) > 0){ //If node has children
    if ($parent == "0")
        echo "<div class='arrowlistmenu'>\n";
    else
    {
        if ($categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]] == 2)
            echo "<ul style='margin-left: 15px' class='subcategoryitems'>\n";
        elseif ($categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]] == 1)
            echo "<ul class='categoryitems'>\n";
    }
    foreach($children as $child)
        renderTree($child);
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
//if($parent != "0") echo "</li>\n";
if($parent == "0") echo "</div>";
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT category_id AS id, parent_category_id AS parent_id, category_name AS category, level AS level FROM sp_categories WHERE is_showing = 1 ORDER BY `order`,category_id");
$childrenTree = array(); //Will store an array of children for each parent
$categoryNames = array(); //Will store category name for each id
//We fill $childrenTree and  $categoryNames from database

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
list($id, $parent_id, $category, $level) = $row;
$categoryNames[(string)$id] = $category;
$categoryNames[(string)$category] = $level;
//$categoryNames[(string)$pid] = $parent_id;
$parent_id = (string)$parent_id;
//  echo $parent_id;
if(!array_key_exists($parent_id, $childrenTree)) 
    $childrenTree[$parent_id] = array();
$childrenTree[$parent_id][] = (string)$id;
}
renderTree();  //This renders the hierarchical tree
?>
<more html>
```

The echo near the bottom of `$parent_id` outputs the ids correctly so I know it is talking to the database.

Edit: Originally, I had the create_header function inside a html_fns.php library, and the render_tree function inside a php_fns.php library to try and seperate those functions which were more displaying html from those which had a large amount of php in them. This had the same result as nesting the render_tree inside the create_header - I nested it to try and make sure it was being defined.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Try placing echo statements in strategic places. I do it all the time. echo($categoryNames[$categoryNames[$parent]]), echo(count($children)), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like because you're defining one function inside another (very rarely a good idea in PHP) your variable scope is a bit messed up. (Defining renderTree() in this way doesn't give it any special scope, it just delays defining it until that point in the code, which makes no difference to anything.)

Specifically, the part where you're defining $childrenTree is in the scope of the create_header() function, so this is not a global variable, and can't be accessed inside renderTree().

I think better code structure will make this a lot easier to debug:

```
// Generally considered a good idea to prepare data before display
$childrenTree = get_nodes_from_db();
// At this point, you shouldn't need to access the DB any more
display_header($childrenTree);

function display_header($childrenTree)
{
    // ...
    renderTree($childrenTree);
    // ...
}
```

If you absolutely insist on using a global variable for $childrenTree rather than passing it around in this way, split the code into these three functions, with no tricksy nesting, and add global $childrenTree at the top of both get_nodes_from_db() and renderTree()

Comment: I've just edited my post to be hopefully clearer on how I got to this stage. Your explanation makes sense and I will try it, hopefully I'll be able to report success shortly!